Why my sufferings do not end?
Please what exactly can be reason why making solah, giving out charity, and fasting to Allah even making alot of duha.
Still yet have not seen changes of my labour, pains and duha on my education and daily life 
Is it possible ALLAH SUBHANAWATA ALLAH HAVE FORGOTTEN ME(one of his slaves)

"on my education", well maybe you are studying a subject that isn't meant for you? Try thinking of other careers, and above all, don't trust what anyone told you on the internet ;-) .

There is a Hadeeth that reads (translated via google):

أَوْحَی اللَّهُ تَعَالَی إِلَی دَاوُدَ علیه‌السلام:
God Almighty revealed to David
یَا دَاوُدُ- إِنِّی وَضَعْتُ خَمْسَةً فِی خَمْسَةٍ- وَ النَّاسُ
یَطْلُبُونَهَا فِی خَمْسَةٍ غَیْرِهَا فَلَا یَجِدُونَهَا
O David: Indeed, I have placed five in five - and the people are looking for it in five other things, but they cannot find it

وَضَعْتُ الْعِلْمَ فِی الْجُوعِ وَ الْجَهْدِ، وَ هُمْ یَطْلُبُونَهُ فِی الشِّبَعِ وَ الرَّاحَةِ فَلَا یَجِدُونَهُ؛

I put the knowledge in the hunger and the endowment- and they are asking for it in the youth and the comfort, so they do not find it

وَضَعْتُ الْعِزَّ فِی طَاعَتِی، وَ هُمْ یَطْلُبُونَهُ فِی خِدْمَةِ السُّلْطَانِ فَلَا یَجِدُونَهُ؛

I put glory in my obedience - and they are looking for it in the service of the Sultan, but they do not find it

وَ وَضَعْتُ الْغِنَی فِی الْقَنَاعَةِ، وَ هُمْ یَطْلُبُونَهُ فِی کَثْرَةِ الْمَالِ فَلَا یَجِدُونَهُ؛

And I put wealth in contentment - and they are looking for it in abundance of money, but they do not find it

وَ وَضَعْتُ رِضَایَ فِی سَخَطِ النَّفْسِ، وَ هُمْ یَطْلُبُونَهُ فِی رِضَا النَّفْسِ فَلَا یَجِدُونَهُ؛

I put my satisfaction in the discontent of the soul - and they search for it in self-satisfaction but do not find it

وَ وَضَعْتُ الرَّاحَةَ فِی الْجَنَّةِ- وَ هُمْ یَطْلُبُونَهَا فِی الدُّنْیَا فَلَا یَجِدُونَهَا.

and I put comfort in Paradise - and they miss it Done it in this world, but they will not find it


[consult here as for reference]

Now, are you looking for comfort in Dunya? You will never find it here! The only way is to live in Paradise even when living on the Earth, and that's when you live by the guidance of Allah, AWJ:

فَمَنْ تَبِعَ هُدَايَ فَلَا خَوْفٌ عَلَيْهِمْ وَ لَا هُمْ يَحْزَنُونَ
whosoever follows My guidance, on them shall be no fear, nor shall
they grieve

Another way to feel happy is to view those who SEEMINGLY are in worse condition than you. You find no one in worse condition that you? Have you even took a look at children and women and injured ones in Gaza? Sometimes they have nothing/no one but Allah, and according to Rabindranath Tagore, Those who have everything but thee, my God, laugh at those who have nothing but thyself, and according to another guy, those who have not God what do they have? even if they own half the globe and the wealth within ...
One day Buhlul went to Harun ArRashid, and told Rashid I am as rich as you, Rashid got mad and asked how is it possible? Buhlul asked how much will you spend to recover your health if you can not eat/drink anything? Rashid said probably half my wealth! Buhlul asked again how much then would you spend to recover your health if you cannot excrete after eating and drinking? He said the rest of my wealth! Buhlul laughed at him as all his wealth was equal to the gift of eating/drinking and excreting, given to almost everyone ...
